# lfs 7.2 compilation of glibc 2.16.0

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am making an linux system following the procedure in lfs. But while i was following the fifth step(i.e. the one before make) on [this page,](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html) i get an error at the last.

```
 configure: error: linker with -z relro support required
```

Now after this if i call make i get an error

```
 make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am running this on a ubuntu 12.04 machine.
How to fix this error?

Comment: ld -V ?  google for when "-z relro" was added to "binutils", I have 'GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.34.el6 20100205' on CentOS 6.x and ' ld --help | grep relro' implies I support it.  Compiling glibc is not for the faint hearted, maybe use beta of a non LTS release 12.10, or Fedora16 and you may find you already have 2.16.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following:-

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

and then retry. This worked for me.